# Decoder::Factory returned null

Tags: java, android

*Hello i have problem in android programming, i try to convert an image file from Uri to bitmap so,*

**This is my imageUri :**

```
"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20171224_004343_960797038.jpg"
```

**and i have this in my program :**

```
 File image = new File(imageUri); 
 BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
```

**but i have this result :**

```
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

**Please any help :)**

Comment: Have you tried `if(!image.exists()){ .......; return;}` ?

Comment: Do you mean that decodeFile() returns null ?

Comment: does file exist?

Comment: Yes i got the image file from gallery, in the previous activity that in send path using :
** intent.putExtra("mCurrentPhotoPath", mCurrentPhotoPath); **
So the image file exist because i display it in the previous activity , but in the next activity i need a bitmap the create mygame , but my bitmap is null